# Binding XML data to Kendo ui menu dynamically

Tags: xml, menu, kendo-ui, bind

I am trying to dynamically create a Kendo menu using XML data. I am reading the data from menu_data.xml. How do you format the data from the xml file into a vertical menu. Here is the following code I have below:
    
    
xml-menu.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.2.804/styles/kendo.common.min.css"
rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.2.804/styles/kendo.kendo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.2.804/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu").kendoMenu({
          dataSource:  new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
             //specify the XML file to read. The same as read: { url: "menu_data.xml" }
               read: "menu_data.xml"
            },
            schema: {
             // specify the the schema is XML
               type: "xml",

             // the XML element which represents a single data record
               data: "/vehicles/vehicle",

             // define the model - the object which will represent a single data record
               model: {
               // configure the fields of the object
                  fields: {
               // the "car" field is mapped to the text of the "car" XML element
                  Name: "car/text()",
               // the "name" field is mapped to the text of the "name" XML element
                  Title: "name/text()",
               // the "color" field is mapped to the text of the "color" XML element
                  Color: "color/text()",
               // the "Price" field is mapped to the text of the "price" XML element
                  Price: "price/text()",
               // the "title" field is mapped to "id" of the "vehicle" XML element
                  Company: "@cover"
               }
             }
           }
        }),
     });
 });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and 


 menu_data.xml

```
<vehicles>
   <vehicle cover="Ford">
       <car>Mustang</car>
       <name>John Smith</name>
       <color>Charcoal</color>
       <price>$20,000</price>
   </vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

Here is an example output of what I kind of want it to look like. :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRn4p.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more detailed researching, I found that the only way you can achieve a dynamically generated Kendo UI Menu widget is to initialize it using a Kendo DataSource. You can bind arrays of JavaScript objects or remote XML, JSON, JSONP data to a DataSource and then initialize the Kendo UI Menu dynamically.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/D54eM/

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
var menu1 =
[{
    text: "Company Name",
    cssClass: "ob-blue",
}, {
    text: "Customer's Name",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
       { text: "Mike Hunt" },
       { text: "Ben Dover" },
       { text: "Harry Cox" },
       { text: "Jack Goff" }
    ]
}, {
    text: "Color",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "Black" },
       { text: "White" },
       { text: "Blue" },
       { text: "Red" }
    ]
}, {
    text: "Prices",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
       { text: "$20,000" },
       { text: "$50,000" },
       { text: "$100,000" },
       { text: "150,000" }
    ]
}, {
    text: "Brand",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "Ford" },
       { text: "Chevrolet" },
       { text: "Audi" },
       { text: "Honda" }
    ]
}, {
    text: "Year",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
       { text: "2008" },
       { text: "2012" },
       { text: "2013" },
       { text: "2014" }
    ]
}, {
    text: "Miles",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "10" },
       { text: "10,000" },
       { text: "45,000" },
       { text: "80,000" }
    ]
}];
```

The link below provides some helpful documentation with the Kendo DataSource:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview

Answer (score -1):

how it is means..... .
you should convert the xml file to StringBuilder and now the String Builder is Covert to the html formate like....

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

and now call the string as return json(str);
then you shoud go to view and write the some Ajax Script and convert into kendo menu. its perfectly working.If anybody wants to know then give a rply to this.I will respond.